# ¿Como filtrar datos de un arreglo de objetos usando RegExp?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Del siguiente arreglo de objetos ¿Cómo puedo filtrar todos los correos que contengan la palabra *director* de la propiedad PUESTO, sin distinguir entre mayúsculas o minúsculas, únicamente que contenga esa palabra?

```
var regs = [
            {EMAIL:"directorgraltest@gmail.com", PUESTO:"DIRECTOR"}, 
            {EMAIL:"testsendmail309@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"}, 
            {EMAIL:"testsendmail3011@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"},
            {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral3_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR A"},   
            {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail32107@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"}, 
            {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail30187@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"},
            {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral2_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR B"}

    ];
```

De forma que me resulte un array así:

```
var filterRegs =['directorgraltest@gmail.com','subdirectorgral2_test@gmail.com','subdirectorgral3_test@gmail.com'];
```

Comment: Qué tiene que ver google-apps-script acá? No lo puedes solucionar sólo con JS? Pregunto eso porque la forma de tu array no tiene los valores entrecomillados, así que no funcionaría en JS, ¿Es un formato propio de google-apps-script?

Comment: Es un log que copié de GAS, estoy haciendo un proyecto y la forma de declarar el array yo se que no es esa, pero para que fuera más claro lo puse así, edito para corregir, Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de realizar lo que planteas utilizando Javascript es la siguiente:

```js
const data = [
    {EMAIL:"directorgraltest@gmail.com", PUESTO:"DIRECTOR"}, 
    {EMAIL:"testsendmail309@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"}, 
    {EMAIL:"testsendmail3011@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"},
    {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral3_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR A"},   
    {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail32107@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"}, 
    {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail30187@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"},
    {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral2_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR B"}
]; 
let results = [];

data.forEach((e) => { 
  if (/director/i.test(e.PUESTO)) results.push(e.EMAIL) 
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es usar el método `filter` para filtrar los elementos y `map` para extraer el dato del email.

Aquí tienes dos ejemplos, el primero utilizando expresiones regulares en la función de filtrado, y el segundo sin utilizarlas, simplemente pasando a mayúsculas el valor de `PUESTO` y buscando la cadena "DIRECTOR":

```js
var regs = [
    {EMAIL:"directorgraltest@gmail.com", PUESTO:"DIRECTOR"}, 
    {EMAIL:"testsendmail309@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"}, 
    {EMAIL:"testsendmail3011@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"},
    {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral3_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR A"},   
    {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail32107@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"}, 
    {EMAIL:"contatestsendmail30187@gmail.com", PUESTO:"BOMBERO"},
    {EMAIL:"subdirectorgral2_test@gmail.com", PUESTO:"SUBDIRECTOR B"}
];
    
var filterRegs = regs
  .filter((x) => /director/i.test(x.PUESTO))
  .map((x) => x.EMAIL);
  
console.log(filterRegs);

filterRegs = regs
  .filter((x) => x.PUESTO.toUpperCase().indexOf('DIRECTOR') >= 0)
  .map((x) => x.EMAIL);
  
console.log(filterRegs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa usando javascript es la siguiente:

- Recorre el objeto `regs` y agrega el EMAIL si se cumple la condición *(la cual es, encontrar la palabra "director)* - independiente de si está o no en mayúscila/minúscula:

Ejemplo:

```js
var regs = [{
    EMAIL: "directorgraltest @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "DIRECTOR"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "testsendmail309 @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "testsendmail3011 @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "SEGURIDAD EXTERNA"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "subdirectorgral3_test @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "SUBDIRECTOR A"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "contatestsendmail32107 @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "BOMBERO"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "contatestsendmail30187 @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "BOMBERO"
  },
  {
    EMAIL: "subdirectorgral2_test @gmail.com",
    PUESTO: "SUBDIRECTOR B"
  }

];

// Arreglo que tendrá los emails.
var filterRegs = [];

// Recorrer los elementos que contenga "regs".
for (var i = 0; i < regs.length; i++) {

  // Verificar si cumple la condición:
  if (regs[i].PUESTO.toLowerCase().indexOf("director") != -1) {

    // Agregar el "EMAIL" si se cumplió la condición.
    filterRegs.push(regs[i].EMAIL);
  }
}

// Aquí está el objeto final:
document.getElementById('divResultados').innerHTML = "var filterRegs = " + JSON.stringify(filterRegs) + ";";
console.log(filterRegs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divResultados"><i>Cargando...</i></div>
```